# Router.navigate not redirecting when button is clicked - Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

My router navigate is not working, when i try to redirect to another component

UserComponent

```
import { BehaviorService } from '../services/behavior.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private usuarioService: UsuarioService,
    private behaveService: BehaviorService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}


 teste() {
      console.log("Passed here ###");
    return this.router.navigate(["teladois"]);
  }
 }
```

```
   <div class="container">
      <form #usuarioForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addUser(usuarioForm)">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="teste()">Teste</button>
      </form>
   </div>
```

app-routing-module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TelaDoisComponent } from './tela-dois/tela-dois.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "usuario",
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: "teladois",
    component: TelaDoisComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

when i clicked the button the method is called, and not redireciting
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3jbk.png

Comment: try one mre time with this `this.router.navigate(["/teladois"])`

Comment: Remove the return when you call `this.router`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably router-outlet might be missing. try to add the below outlet wherever you want your routing content need to be displayed

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```